# Automatically sharding MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning, scale, sharding

Right now, I'm dealing with a TON (trust me) of data that needs to be available in real-time for fast reads and writes to customers.  The backend storage system that we're using is Oracle, but we'd like to replace our big, beefy machines with a leaner system.

For various reasons, we can't use Cassandra, and we're testing (but I'm scared of) MongoDB (it's really young and is missing some critical features), so I was thinking about sharding a bunch of MySQL instances.

Is there a good system to manage this, or do I have to roll my own?  I've found a few projects but it's unclear to me if they support adding/removing shards on the fly.

Comment: What language is the code base in? That might help focus us in a useful direction for suggestions on sharding solutions.

Comment: @mlschechter how language will matter in doing sharding ?... can you explain a little bit??

Answer (score 6):

You can definitely implement database sharding with MySQL very effectively. If your sharding scheme is simple it can be done in your application layer, but if its more complex you may want to use a tool. A lot of the options are described on our site here, as well as the advanced options we support.

You can learn more about the options here:

http://www.dbshards.com/articles/database-sharding-whitepapers/

Also its important to consider the entire lifecycle for a sharded environment, including failover, active-active replication, backups, restores, and re-sharding as you mentioned above.

FYI we have customers reading and writing very high volumes with 1000s of concurrent users in cloud environments (with slow I/O), and even faster in data center environments. Sharding definitely can be incredibly effective, with writes scaling linearly and reads often better than linear (because more data is cached in the database).

Answer (score 0):

Good question! I must say I agree with @cisaacson that when your scheme becomes a little more complex you may want to look into some sort of db management. You could do sharding on your own, but as I understand you are dealing with a complicated scenario. I have recently researched this issue for a possible project, which is how I got into sharding (and found your post). Take into account that sharding can be a bit of a challenge... So when planning such a migration, you might want to think about partitioning, which can sometimes be a simpler solution (here is an interesting comparison of partitioning / [mysql sharding](http://xeround.com/blog/2011/11/mysql-sharding-vs-mysql-partitioning) and the basic idea on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) if needed). Some of the challenges I know of: how to replicate scripts, how do you publish objects to all shards? What about versioning? And this doesn’t even take into account obvious issues like the amount of memory needed to access the data, the amount of writes that can really burden the slave machine, etc.. Seeing you wrote this a while ago, I’m curious as to what you decided to do in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

[Sharding-JDBC](https://github.com/dangdangdotcom/sharding-jdbc) is a JDBC driver for shard databases and tables. maybe you can try to use it.